# Is "char*" in argument a pointer to a single char or a char array?

Tags: c, pointers

This is a general question about C.(I dont have a lot of experience coding in C)
So, if I have a function that takes a `char*` as an argument. How to know whether its a pointer to a single `char` or a `char` array, because if it's a `char` array I can expect a `\0` but if it's not a char array then I wouldn't want to search for `\0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot determine how many bytes are referenced by a pointer. You need to keep track of this yourself.

Comment: Aha, that's what I thought! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

> **Is `char*` in argument a pointer to a single `char` or a `char` array?**

Yes.

A parameter of type `char*` is *always* a pointer to a `char` object (or a null pointer, not pointing to anything, if that's what the caller passes as the corresponding argument).

It's not a pointer to an array (that would be, for example, a pointer of type `char(*)[42]`), but the usual way to access the elements of an array is via a pointer to the element type, not to the whole array. Why? Because an actual pointer-to-array must always specify the length of the array (`42` in my example), which is inflexible and doesn't let the same function deal with arrays of different lengths.

A `char*` parameter *can* be treated just as a pointer to a single `char` object. For example, a function that gets a character of input might be declared like this:

```
bool get_next_char(char *c);
```

The idea here is that the function's result tells you whether it was successful; the actual input character is "returned" via the pointer.  (This is a contrived example; `<stdio.h>` already has several functions that read characters from input, and they don't use this mechanism.)

Compare the `strlen` function, which computes the length of a string:

```
size_t strlen(const char *s);
```

`s` points to the first element of an *array* of `char`; internally, `strlen` uses that pointer to traverse the array, looking for the terminating `'\0'` character.

Ignoring the `const`, there's no real difference between the `char*` parameters for these two functions. In fact, C has no good way to distinguish between these cases: a pointer that simply points to a single object vs. a pointer that points to the first element of an array.

It does have a *bad* way to make that distinction. For example, `strlen` could be declared as:

```
size_t strlen(const char s[]);
```

But C doesn't really have parameters of array type at all.  The parameter declaration `const char s[]` is "adjusted" to `const char *s`; it means exactly the same thing. You can even declare a length for something that looks like an array parameter:

```
void foo(char s[42]);
```

and it will be quietly ignored; the above really means exactly the same thing as:

```
void foo(char *s);
```

The `[42]` may have some documentation value, but a comment has the same value -- and the same significance as far as the compiler is concerned.

Any distinction between a pointer to a single object and a pointer to the first element of an array has to be made by the programmer, preferably in the documentation for the function.

Furthermore, this mechanism doesn't let the function know how long the array is. For `char*` pointers in particular, it's common to use the null character `'\0'` as a marker for the end of a string -- which means it's the callers responsibility to ensure that that marker is actually there. Otherwise, you can pass the length as a separate argument, probably of type `size_t`. Or you can use any other mechanism you like, as long as everything is done consistently.

> ...  because if it's a `char` array I can expect a `\0` ...

No, you can't, at least not necessarily. A `char*` could easily point to the first element of a `char` array *that's not terminated by a `'\0'` character* (i.e., that doesn't contain a *string*). You can impose such a requirement if you like. The standard library functions that operate on strings impose that requirement -- but they don't enforce it. For example, if you pass a pointer to an unterminated array to `strlen`, the behavior is undefined.

Recommended reading: Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: Bravo, except that char s[42] does have documentation value, along with some compile-time value as well since sizeof (char[42) is different from sizeof (char*).

Comment: @MikeHousky: The documentation value could be met with a comment, which has just as much meaning to the compiler. And yes, `sizeof (char[42])` does differ from `sizeof (char*)` -- but `sizeof param` is the same for either declaration of `param`.

Comment: Hmm.  Had to see it to believe it, but so it does. I think I used to know this once, because an old varargs-type of call would have to know how long the actual parameter on the stack is in order to skip over it.  Curiously, the way to get the correct size behavior seems to be pointer-to-array.  (char*)[42] is binary-compatible (but not source compatible) with char*. Oh, well. s/Bravo, but/Bravo! Perhaps/ and nuke the sizeof remark.

Comment: @MikeHousky: `char(*)[42]` *may or may not* be binary-compatible with `char*`. There's no guarantee that different pointer types have the same representation (except for a few special cases like `char*` vs. `void*` and `struct foo*` vs. `struct bar*`). Most modern implementations make all pointers the same size, but not all do.

Comment: I don't see how you can pass different-sized data pointers and still have printf("%p") work. C99/C11 6.2.3.2[7] requires that object pointers be convertible to any other object pointer type and back without loss (so the information content in any two data pointer types must be the same). The only restriction is that alignment may not be right in the new type.  A char can't have alignment problems, so that's not an issue.  In fact, pointer-array duality and the requirement that & "yields the address of its operand" means that every scalar of type T is aligned to be a T[1] array.

Comment: @MikeHousky: `printf`'s `%p` format requires an argument of type `void*`. Passing an `int*`, for example, has undefined behavior. You need to cast the argument to `void*`: `int *ptr; ... printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr);` Conversion from `int*` to `void*`, like conversion from, say, `int` to `double`, may require some non-trivial operations, not just copying the representation. If your implementation happens to give all pointers the same representation (as most do), you can probably get away with passing pointers of arbitrary types to `printf("%p", ...)`; that doesn't mean the behavior is defined.

Comment: @JackCColeman: Look again. I was specifically talking about `strlen`, not about any arbitrary user-written function.

Comment: There's a fun (?) new C99 feature, where `void f(T arr[static 42])` *does* have a special meaning: the `static` implies that you must pass to `f()` an array of at least 42 elements.

Comment: @MikeHousky The C11 citation is §6.3.2.3 7 (not 6.2.3.2).  Further it does not require "without loss", but such the the round trip conversion results in 2 pointers that compare equally - they may have different bit patterns, but equal value.

Comment: @torek `void f(T arr[static 42])` does mean that the argument must be, not an array, but a pointer to the initial element of an array with at least 42 elements. But if it isn't (e.g., if you pass a null pointer or a pointer to a singleton `char` object), no diagnostic is required; the behavior is undefined. It's intended to permit better warnings, but a conforming implementation could ignore the `static`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that a char array is **NOT** terminated with a `\0` in which case you need to know the length of the array.  Also, it is possible for an array to have a length of 1, in which case you have one character with no terminating `\0`.

The nice thing about `C` is that you get to define the details about data structures, thus you are **NOT** limited to a char array always ending with `\0`.

Some of the terms used to describe C data structures are synonymous.  For example, an array is sequential series of data elements, an array of characters is a string, and a string can be terminated with a null char (`\0`).

Comment: Yeah, I did get this part! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, although surely worth mentioning, this somehow is not an answer to the question and should have better be placed as comment to the question.

Comment: @alk, the answers did not explore this aspect of strings.

Comment: But who says it is a string?  That's the point of the question.  Nor is it necessarily an array.